# Elixir: defmacro and benchmark of pipline

Tags: macros, elixir, benchmarking, duration

I have macro which should help me to meaaure latency:

```
  defmacro instrument_duration(endpoint_name, block) do
    quote do
      {time, value} = :timer.tc(fn -> unquote(block) end)
      Histogram.observe(
        [name: :endpoint_duration_seconds, labels: [endpoint_name]],
        time
      )
      value
    end
  end
```

And following code that is using it:

```
    response =
      Instrumenter.instrument_duration(id,
        do_handle(params, context)
        |> prepare_response())
```

But I get `Reason:undef\n', options: []` error. What I did wrong here? Is it correct way at all?

Comment: `labels: [endpoint_name]` → `labels: [unquote(endpoint_name)]`, as you should have been told by warning during compilation. Compiler warnings are not to be ignored, if you want to have a robust code. Also, it’d be great to see the whole error message, please post it next time.

Comment: Thank you, Aleksei! Btw, my error messages are very poor, like that: `[msg: 'Unexpected error during request processing. Handler:\'Elixir.App.Module\'; Reason:undef\n', options: []]` Can I do something with that? Does something swallow full error messages in my code?

Comment: Eh. I have no idea what “request” does mean here and how it gets processed, but I’d clearly isolate the testing to test this particular macro only. Like mock `Histogram` and test `Instrumenter.instrument_duration/2` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am to put this as an answer here.

**TL;DR:** `labels: [endpoint_name]` → `labels: [unquote(endpoint_name)]`

---

Your code does not unquote `endpoint_name` inside the quoted block, resulting in the unsuccessful compiler’s attempt to resolve `endpoint_name` within the context of the quoted block.

Luckily enough, [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) provides warnings during the compilation stage, and there must have been somewhat like

```
warning: variable "endpoint_name" is unused (if the variable
         is not meant to be used, prefix it with an underscore)
```

Compiler warnings are not to be ignored if one wants to have a robust code, they are provided on purpose and are to be taken into consideration.